# How to set Page Layout view mode for .xls files using apache poi?

Tags: apache, apache-poi, xls, page-layout

I am creating an .xls excel file using apache poi.
I need to set the Page Layout view by default. I am not able to find an api to do this.

I did look at a related question on .xlsx files - 
[Set page view mode in excel file using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861001/set-page-view-mode-in-excel-file-using-apache-poi)

But i didn't find an equivalent way for .xls files.

Pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows. Using Excel, create an empty workbook with a single sheet. While viewing this workbook using Excel, set the view to Page Layout, then save the empty excel spreadsheet to a file e.g. "empty.xls". Next, in your Java program, instead of creating a workbook from scratch, read the empty file as your starting point as in the example below.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("empty.xls");
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue("You will see me in Page Layout View");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.xls"));
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
```

When you open up the Excel file "test.xls" it will already be in Page Layout view mode.